# Table text out of page

Tags: tables, overleaf, layout

I want to create a table on overleaf Latex but the table keeps exceeding the page bounds.

My table code is this:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Advantages and disadvantages of \acrshort{Wi-Fi}}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|p{0.8\linewidth}|}
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\textbf{Advantages}}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\textbf{Disadvantages}}}                                                   \tabularnewline \hline
Ability to penetrate objects \n                 & Power consumption 
                                                \tabularnewline \hline
Simple to add or remove nodes                  & Complexity                                                                                                  \tabularnewline \hline
128-bit AES encryption provides a secure connection       & Radio waves in the network can interfere with the equipment                                   \tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:wad}   
\end{table}
```

I think its because the text on the left is long and is pushing the text on the right and the table out of the page.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class do you employ? What's the paper size, and how wide is the textblock? Which font and which font size do you employ? How or where is `\acrshort` defined? How is `\n` defined?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Either try something along the lines of `\begin{tabular}{|*{2}{p{\dimexpr0.5\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}|}}` or `\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}` (needs the `tabularx` package).

Comment: Thanks :)
I did not put all the document because its a little bit big where the table is supposed to go.
```\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside]{thesis}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{time}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{pgfgantt}
\usepackage[acronym, nopostdot, toc , nonumberlist, nogroupskip]{glossaries}
\usepackage{adjustbox}```

Hope this helps. Sorry for the noobness

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the `tabularx` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Advantages and disadvantages of \texttt{Wi-Fi}}
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{|L|L|}
    \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{{\textbf{Advantages}}}     & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{{\textbf{Disadvantages}}}                                                   \tabularnewline \hline
Ability to penetrate objects n                 & Power consumption
                                                \tabularnewline \hline
Simple to add or remove nodes                  & Complexity                                                                                                  \tabularnewline \hline
128-bit AES encryption provides a secure connection       & Radio waves in the network can interfere with the equipment                                   \tabularnewline \hline
\end{tabularx}
\label{tab:wad}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(red lines shows text borders)